# Adding text when Switching image on click

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/guspersson/s8qLg7ur/) to switch images. I need to add a different caption text to each one like in the pictures below, i guess there must be a way to add this text on the script.

```html
<script>
    function change() {
   var img1 = "http://placehold.it/350x150",
       img2 = "http://placehold.it/200x200";
   var imgElement = document.getElementById('test');
   
   imgElement.src = (imgElement.src === img1)? img2 : img1;
}
</script>
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" id="test" onclick ="change();"/>
```

[image]

Comment: what is bottom text? What is the expected end result?

Comment: Sorry, a different caption at the bottom of each image

Comment: Can you have a `span` located below the image and replace the text as you need it when you replace the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, if you can have a `span` below your image you can switch your text the same way you switch the image.

```html
<script>
    function change() {
   var img1 = "http://placehold.it/350x150",
       img2 = "http://placehold.it/200x200",
       img1Text = 'Image 1 Text',
       img2Text = 'Image 2 Text';
       
   var imgElement = document.getElementById('test'),
       imgTextElement = document.getElementById('testText');
   
   imgElement.src = (imgElement.src === img1)? img2 : img1;
   imgTextElement.innerText = (imgTextElement.innerText === img1Text)? img2Text: img1Text;
}
</script>
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" id="test" onclick ="change();"/>
<span style="display: block" id='testText'>Image 1 Text</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function change() {
   var img1 = "http://placehold.it/350x150",
       img2 = "http://placehold.it/200x200";
   var imgElement = document.getElementById('test');
   
   imgElement.src = (imgElement.src === img1)? img2 : img1;
   document.getElementById("test-span").innerHTML = (imgElement.src === img1)? "img2" : "img1";
}
```

```css
div{
 display:flex;
}
```

```html
<div><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" id="test" onclick ="change();"/>
<span id="test-span">img1</span>
</div>
```